# C++ Controlling Audio through specific earphones

Tags: c++, audio

Is there a built-in function in Windows for controlling audio between two different earphones (in one set? ie, left earphone and right earphone) Or, is there an audio library you'd recommend to me for this purpose?

Thanks in advace!

Comment: Do your earphones even support that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'audio'? You want different tracks coming out of each channel? Are you talking about the balance as in the volume of each earphone?